# Do I need to populate a foreign key when creating it?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, foreign-keys

When creating a foreign key in SQL developer do I need to put the same data in the foreign key that's used from the second table?

for example:

```
Table 1 - Driver
PK - Driver_ID
FK - REG
Name
address
telephone number

Table 2 - Vehicles
PK - REG
make
model
colour
year
```

Will I need to put the data that I have for Reg in the vehicle table into Reg in the driver table when creating a database?

Answer (score 2):

No. Not when creating the database.

The Foreign Key only needs to be present when an entry in a referencing table row refers to it.

Example:

This is OK:

```
INSERT INTO Driver (REG, Name, address, telephone number) 
VALUES (NULL, "John Doe", 1 The Road", "12345678")
```

But in order to do this:

```
INSERT INTO Driver (REG, Name, address, telephone number) 
VALUES (1, "John Doe", 1 The Road", "12345678")
```

An entry with PK = 1 must exist in the vehicle table,

```
Vehicles
1    Ford    Spirit   Blue    1990
```